# Error 422 after installing gitlab on centos 7

Tags: centos, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I got into trouble after installing `Gitlab` on `CentOs7`. For the first time I was redirected to the admin password creation page and after the password for the admin user, the server sent error.

```
422
The change you requested was rejected.
```

I had set the url value based on the site guide.

> Set the external_url in /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb:

```
external_url "https://example.com/gitlab"
```

I checked the links below for similar situations. I didn't find the right answer. My server was in the local area and had no internet access.

[Error 422 after installing gitlab on Ubuntu 18.04](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/3965)

[After Update Error: "422 The change you requested was rejected."](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/53085)

[Error 422 after installing Gitlab on Ubuntu 16.04](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/52133)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a mistake when installing Gitlab. In the `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` file I put the local gitlab address with `https` but due to the local server setup there was no "let's encrypt" service and I did not intend to access the site via ssl. I modified the address in the file and turne "https" to "http". After modifying the following commands, the problem was fixed.

`sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

`sudo gitlab-ctl restart`